# Logic App failed but the web activity in ADF calling this logic app has success status

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I have a web activity within ADF pipeline which calls the Logic app to get a file from azure blob storage depending on some switch conditions and send email notification with the file as an attachment.

adf pipeline -> web activity -> logic app http trigger -> switch condition -> gets file content from azure blob storage if the condition is satisfied -> send email with file as attachment

I was testing this component for scenarios where the switch condition is satisfied and the file doesn't exists. The logic app as expected fails with the resource not found error, but the web activity completes successfully.

Has anyone faced similar situation, any pointers would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your http triggered logic app is by default asynchronous. This means when you call the API/logic app, you will get a 201 response code indicating that the Logic app has received the request but does not indicate if it has finished processing the request. This is what is happening in your case. To confirm, you can check if the response code is 201. The behavior is similar when you attempt to execute the logic app via a request from Postman.

To fix this, you will need to make the logic app synchronous. To do this, you will need to add a success response step at the end of the logic app to respond with a 200. You will need to add additional response steps to respond with a failure response code wherever your logic app may fail. You can refer how to set your logic app using this [LINK](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6264/how-to-call-logic-app-synchronously-from-azure-data-factory/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not aware of this, will try it out.

Comment: Hi @Aragon. Any luck with your issue? If my answer resolves your question, kindly mark it as the correct answer so this question can be closed.

Comment: Hi @Aragon, Did my response answer your question? If so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Anupam, your post resolved the issue I was having.